# Jquery .Load not working in android browser but works in Firefox mobile browser on same device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Please i am trying to load a div from an external page "page2.html#newupdate" into another div "#localupdate" in my current page "page1.html" using Jquery .Load.

And unfortunately, it is not working in the android browser version 5.1 but works in Firefox mobile browser version 45.0.1 on the same device. It also works in desktop Chrome and Firefox too.

please why? 
Any best idea would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

JS:

```
  /*
I AM TESTING AN INTERNET AVAILABILITY FIRST. 
BY SEND A REQUEST TO THE jquery.min.js FILE ONLINE. 
THEN IF SUCCESSFUL, TRIGGER MY FUNCTION loadNewupdate().
*/

function loadNewupdate() {
    $("#localupdate").empty();
$( "#localupdate" ).load( "page2.html#newupdate" ); //.trigger("create"):
document.getElementById("localupdate").style.dispaly = "block";};

$( document ).ready(function ping(){
     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js',
      crossDomain: 'true',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result){        
    loadNewupdate (); },     
   });  
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- PAGE1.HTML -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1" align="center">    
<div id="localupdate" style="display:none;">
NEW UPDATE HERE... 
</div>
</div>

<!-- PAGE2.HTML -->
<script>
$("#page2").live('pageinit', function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages=true;
});
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" align="center">    
<div id="newupdate" style="display:block;">

    <a href="http://newlink1.com" target="_parent"><img  alt="new image" src="http://imgfile.com/1.jpg"/></a>               
    <a href="http://newlink2.com" target="_parent"><img  alt="new image" src="http://imgfile.com/2.jpg"/></a>               
    <a href="http://newlink3.com" target="_parent"><img  alt="new image" src="http://imgfile.com/3.jpg"/></a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The default Android Browser is not very powerful. I don't know what technology it uses, but I'd guess that it doesn't support advanced things like cross domain and CORS.

Comment: Thank you RoToRa,  so please what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this fiddle work with your Android browser? https://jsfiddle.net/amwu5bpg/

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
document.getElementById("#localupdate").style.dispaly = "block";};
```

Does following actually work? Creating a named function and execute it at the same time? What happens if you remove "ping" ?

```
$( document ).ready(function ping(){
```

.live is deprecated. Replace it with .on :

```
$("#page2").live
```

Comment: Yezzz, thank you very much for your answer & also identifying my typo: document.getElementById("#localupdate").style.dispaly = "block";}; . It unfortunately appeared here on stackoverflow but on my system everything is fine. But i tested your answer and still not working.

Comment: By the way, my main problem is why my code works in firefox mobile browser, firefox desktop browser, chrome desktop browser and not working in the android mobile browser version 5.1.

Comment: Hmm, it may well be a limitation in that browser. BTW, you should also remove the trailing comma after succes: function() { }

Comment: does it work if you remove the ajax test and just call loadNewupdate() after .ready?

Comment: CORS seems to be supported in Android Browser from version 4.4 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)

Comment: Thanks Yezzz, i took off the trailing comma after succes: function() { } but nothing happened. And i also took off the entire ajax test and called loadNewupdate() after .ready but nothing happened too.

Comment: One more thing I noticed in the code you're using jQuery.support.cors instead of $.support.cors ...